# Tesseract TIF to PDF error: Error in l_generateCIDataForPdf: cid not made from file

Tags: tesseract, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu: 18.04
Tesseract: 5.3.1

When I use `pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr()` to convert TIF Files to PDF, I get the following error:
*Error in l_generateCIDataForPdf: cid not made from file*

Can someone help me understand what the exact issue is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from [leptonica](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica) library. Use the version 1.82.0 or the latest code. See [issue 659](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/issues/659) for details.